# Where can I find a list of workflow manager updates?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-on-prem, workflow-manager

I seem to have missed the latest update for workflow manager update CU5. Microsoft says to check at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/workflowteam/ for updates to workflow manager. This page hasn't had an entry since 2017.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep in mind WFM is more or less a dead-end product, so lack of updates would be expected. There is one additional CU, CU5, which is available from  [Description of the Cumulative Update 5 for Workflow Manager 1.0](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4055730/description-of-the-cumulative-update-5-for-workflow-manager-1-0).

Comment: I don't mind that it's dead. I am more at issue with never knowing that the update was released and microsoft suggested link not showing this.

Comment: You can use the RSS feed for downloads.microsoft.com, as well - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/rssfeeds.xml?type=all&biq=rss_alldownloads_all. That's about it. There's no other definitive source to watch.